# DBUNIT Depended Tables

Tags: java, jdbc, junit, dbunit

I am using DBUNIT for exporting my dataset as XML. I wonder is there any "simple" way to get all dependet tables and data by given table name and some criterion?

```
    private void exportDBDepended() throws Exception {

     String[] depTableNames = TablesDependencyHelper.getAllDependentTables(connection, "dbo.Users" );
     IDataSet depDataset = connection.createDataSet( depTableNames );
     FlatXmlDataSet.write(depDataset, new FileOutputStream("dependents.xml")); 

}
```

This gives me all records and dependet data, but I would like to fetch only top 100 records, or some other condition for table.

Thanks in advance,
Dario

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to solve my requirement programmatically,  but http://jailer.sourceforge.net/ will be more than eneugh for preparing XML DB data.